# When Building a Dockerfile I can't have Perl and curl / git in the same definition

Tags: github, docker, alpine-linux

I am trying to use a Dockerfile to build a small export that has Perl, curl and git in it for use with GitHub as a chroot environment.  Any attempt to put either curl or git in the Dockerfile ends up removing directories from the exported tar file.  I can combine Perl with other packages such as Firefox and do end up with an usable tar.

This is the Dockerfile.  As stated, if I ask for just Perl or anything but curl / git with Perl it does work.

```
FROM gliderlabs/alpine:3.4

RUN apk add --update \
    curl \
    perl-dev \
    git \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/perl", "-de0"]
```

Any insights are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try

- try additional "RUN" commands for each install
- remove the cache after each step
- while building docker image use no cache option. `docker build -no-cache`

Comment: Thanks.  I did try each of those.  As noted above, my exported tar file does not contain the executables.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your Dockerfile without issue:

```
$ cat df.alpine
FROM gliderlabs/alpine:3.4

RUN apk add --update \
    curl \
    perl-dev \
    git \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

$ docker build -t alpinetest -f df.alpine .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 37.89 kB
Step 1 : FROM gliderlabs/alpine:3.4
3.4: Pulling from gliderlabs/alpine
a03be5b52c0f: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:f34605566fc0827029c786094d104703f68953a7845d5bf4334c4c50fea6200c
Status: Downloaded newer image for gliderlabs/alpine:3.4
 ---> eeae34df12d9
Step 2 : RUN apk add --update     curl     perl-dev     git   && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
 ---> Running in 21aeec842908
fetch http://alpine.gliderlabs.com/alpine/v3.4/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://alpine.gliderlabs.com/alpine/v3.4/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/9) Installing ca-certificates (20160104-r4)
(2/9) Installing libssh2 (1.7.0-r0)
(3/9) Installing libcurl (7.49.1-r0)
(4/9) Installing curl (7.49.1-r0)
(5/9) Installing expat (2.1.1-r1)
(6/9) Installing pcre (8.38-r1)
(7/9) Installing git (2.8.3-r0)
(8/9) Installing perl (5.22.2-r0)
(9/9) Installing perl-dev (5.22.2-r0)
Executing busybox-1.24.2-r9.trigger
Executing ca-certificates-20160104-r4.trigger
OK: 69 MiB in 20 packages
 ---> 7ee2fd822c7a
Removing intermediate container 21aeec842908
Successfully built 7ee2fd822c7a

$ docker run --rm -it alpinetest /bin/sh
/ # which git
/usr/bin/git
/ # which perl
/usr/bin/perl
/ # which curl
/usr/bin/curl

/ # perl -v

This is perl 5, version 22, subversion 2 (v5.22.2) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi

Copyright 1987-2015, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.

/ # curl --version
curl 7.49.1 (x86_64-alpine-linux-musl) libcurl/7.49.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2h zlib/1.2.8 libssh2/1.7.0
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets

/ # git --version
git version 2.8.3
```

If your output is different from the above, please update your question with more details.

---

Edit: Per your request I also included an export and the binaries show up without issue:

```
$ docker create --name alpinetestc alpinetest /bin/true
$ docker export alpinetestc | gzip >alpinetest.tgz
$ tar -tvzf alpinetest.tgz usr/bin/git
-rwxr-xr-x 0/0         1944216 2016-05-26 10:44 usr/bin/git
$ tar -tvzf alpinetest.tgz usr/bin/curl
-rwxr-xr-x 0/0          173912 2016-05-30 12:11 usr/bin/curl
$ tar -tvzf alpinetest.tgz usr/bin/perl
-rwxr-xr-x 0/0            9872 2016-05-16 06:22 usr/bin/perl
```

It doesn't appear that you've provided enough details to recreate your problem.

Comment: I was expecting to see these in the tar file.  My generated tar file only contains bin, dev and etc top-level folders.....I can't find perl, curl or git executables in them.

Comment: Here's the set of commands that was given to export for use in GitHub.<br>docker build -f docker.perl -t docker.perl .

docker create --name docker.perl docker.perl /bin/true

docker export docker.perl | gzip > docker.perl.tar.gz

Comment: Hello.  Thanks for checking this.  I couldn't make it work using Docker for Windows on Windows 10 Pro nor using Docker Toolbox on Windows 10 Home.

I can try building the export on a Linux machine to see if that is what is causing me grief.

Comment: Hello:

  The issue turned out to be that when validating the resulting export in Windows using WinRar, the symlinks don't resolve properly and made the files appear to be missing.

  When adding only perl, there were no symlinks thereby no issues in validating the file.

  Thank you for pointing out that it did build properly under Linux.  It was after that that I realized the symlinks were casuing me the worries.

IskiE

Comment: @IskieIsketerol Thanks for the follow up, and glad to hear Docker isn't broken, at least in this way. Running Docker natively on Linux has certainly removed a lot of issues for me that I see others experiencing.